# Proof of the fact that non-abelian simple group of finite order has an even number of elements

Tags: group-theory

IN Herstein has stated in the books *Topics in Algebra* that a proof of the above conjecture was given by Walter Feit and John Thompson.(he defines a simple group as one which has no-nontrivial homomorphic images).

Question: Can anyone please show me a proof of the above conjecture using the group theory background in Herstein's text or at least one I can understand?I am currently studying about homomorphisms from there.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are currently studying homomorphisms, then the Feit-Thompson proof is probably a bit beyond your appetite (from [this reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit-Thompson_theorem), the final paper is 255 pages long).

Comment: It seems bit is an understatement. Not knowing enough is so stifling.

Comment: The proof is very advanced, far too advanced for beginning algebra, and I suspect it is a very tiny subset of methematicians who have read and understood the full proof. Frustrating, since it is one of those things I've always wished was easily comprehended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't at all an answer to your question, but as you've already seen, you're not going to get one!

I thought you might be interested to know that there is now a formally verified computer proof of the Feit-Thompson Theorem.  It took six years to produce and was completed just last year.  [Here's](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/gonthierproof-101112.aspx) an article about it.

Comment: By the way, if anyone isn't sure why the Feit-Thompson Theorem, which says that every group of odd order is soluble, is the same as the statement in the title of this question, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265362/every-simple-group-of-odd-order-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-p-iff-every-gro)

Answer (score 1):

Many decades after the original proof of the theorem was published, the proof was laid out in two quite approachable (at least as far as I have read into them...they came out after I was working in industry) books: Bender and Glauberman's *Local Analysis for the Odd Order Theorem* and Peterfalvi's *Character Theory for the Odd Order Theorem*.  By "quite approachable" I mean "quite readable by a graduate student specializing in algebra".  However, their utility for a graduate student may depend on whether the techniques involved are likely to be useful for any open problems, which I am not in a position to judge.

Sufficient background for those books would be the I. Martin Isaacs books *Finite Group Theory* and *Character Theory of Finite Groups*.