# How can $G$ a simple group always be isomorphic to $Z_p$ for some prime $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it not a necessary condition that the order of two groups must be equal for them to be isomorphic?

Does "$G$ is a simple group of odd order" somehow imply "$|G|$ is prime"?"

If not, I don't see how it can't be the case that $|G|$ is some odd composite number, so it couldn't be isomorphic to any $Z_p$ where $p$ is prime.

Comment: Yes, isomorphic groups have the same order. Every simple group of odd order has prime order; this is the Feit-Thompson theorem, a very deep and very difficult (and very important) result.

Comment: For the second sentence in the above comment see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265362/every-simple-group-of-odd-order-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-p-iff-every-gro).

Comment: A simple group is one with no non-trivial normal subgroups.  When a non-trivial group is both simple and abelian, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime $p$.  As my graduate professor liked to say, these are the "simple simple groups".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it not a necessary condition that the order of two groups must be
>   equal for them to be isomorphic?

It is. Any two isomorphic groups have the same order.

> Does "$G$ is a simple group of odd order" somehow imply "$\lvert G \rvert$ is prime"?"

Yes it does. This is equivalent to the [Feit-Thompson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem) that every finite group of odd order is solvable, as discussed in the question [Every simple group of odd order is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p} $ iff every group of odd order is solvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/265362/59435).
That theorem was proved in the 255-page 1963 paper [Solvability of groups of odd order](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103053941).